# Caching ActiveRecord model instance methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Say I have a user model.  It has an instance method called status.  Status is not an association.  It doesn't follow any active record pattern because it's a database already in production.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  

  def status
    Connection.where(machine_user_id: self.id).last
  end    

end
```

So I do this.

```
@users = User.all
```

First of all I can't eager load the status method.

```
@users.includes(:status).load
```

Second of all I can't cache that method within the array of users.

```
Rails.cache.write("user", @users)
```

The status method never gets called until the view layer it seems like.

What is the recommended way of caching this method.

Maybe this instance method is not what I want to do.  I've looked at scope but it doesn't look like what I want to do.

Maybe I just need an association?  Then I get the includes and I can cache.

But can associations handle complex logic.  In this case the instance method is a simple query.  What if I have complex logic in that instance method?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Have You tried to encapsulate this logic inside some plain Ruby object like this (I wouldn't use this for very large sets though):

```
class UserStatuses
  def self.users_and_statuses
    Rails.cache.fetch "users_statuses", :expires_in => 30.minutes do
      User.all.inject({}) {|hsh, u| hsh[u.id] = u.status; hsh }
    end
  end
end
```

After that You can use some helper method to access cached version

```
class User < ActiverRecord::Base
  def cached_status
    UserStatuses.users_and_statuses[id]
  end
end
```

It doesn't solve Your eager loading problem, Rails doesn't have any cache warming up techniques built in. But by extracting like this, it's easily done by running rake task in Cron.

Also in this case I don't see any problems with using association. Rails associations allows You to submit different options including foreign and primary keys.

Comment: I'm actually already doing this.  Rails.cache.read("connection_history_#{self.id}").  I just gave the example using a query.  Even though it's cached I would still like to cache all of it in one go.  The load time is still bad because it's doing a cache fetch on every row.

Comment: What do You mean by "cache all of it in one go", You also want to cache a user object?

Comment: I want to throw the whole User object with the instance methods evaluated into one cache.  Instead of reading user cache, then when I'm displaying it, it reading the individual caches for the cached statuses.  Hope that makes sense.

Surely this comes up more often then not.  Think about an instance method called full_name.  It take first and last name and concats it.  I want to put the User object in cache with the full_name method evaluated.

Comment: Don't see much use of caching full_name because first_name, last_name would be already cached and overhead of concatenating them is negligible. But from what You are saying I think You want to look at this: https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache